# Help locating conflicting options error

Tags: biblatex, errors, compiling

I have a conflicting options error message, and I can't figure out what is causing it. Please see my set-up below. I realise this a pretty complex set-up, so I'm not looking for a full analysis of it; just hoping that someone might be able to spot something simple that I've missed, with just a quick read. Many thanks in advance.

The error message (the line number is sadly not helpful...):

```
example.tex:0 Conflicting options.
```

My document header:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx, epsfig, subfig, setspace, fixltx2e, amsmath, textcomp, gensymb, csquotes, floatrow, siunitx, xpatch, nomencl, rotating, fullpage, appendix, epstopdf}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp, punctfont, sorting=nyt, sortcites=noneyear, eprint=false, firstinits=true, doi=false, url=false, isbn=false, backend=biber, maxbibnames=99, maxcitenames=2, uniquelist=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{issn}}
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{note}}
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{number}}
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{language}}
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{Language}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{#1}% no postnote prefix in "normal" citation commands
\DeclareFieldFormat{multipostnote}{#1}% no postnote prefix in "multicite" commands
\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1}% no prefix for the `pages` field in the bibliography
\DeclareFieldFormat
  [article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished]
  {title}{#1\isdot}
\DeclareFieldFormat*{volume}{\mkbibbold{#1}}%make volume number bold in the bibliography
\renewbibmacro{in:}{}

\DeclareFieldFormat{author}{#1\addcomma\space}
\let\oldmultinamedelim\multinamedelim
\let\oldfinalnamedelim\finalnamedelim
\renewcommand*{\multinamedelim}{\space\bibstring{and}\space}

\AtBeginBibliography{
  \renewcommand*{\multinamedelim}{\oldmultinamedelim}
  \renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\oldfinalnamedelim}
}
\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\addspace}
\DeclareSortingScheme{noneyear}{
 \sort{\citeorder}
 \sort{\field{year}}
}
\DeclareFieldFormat[book]{title}{#1}

\DeclareFloatFont{footnotesize}{\footnotesize}
\floatsetup[table]{font=footnotesize}
\floatsetup[table, figure]{\centering}
\floatsetup[table]{style=plaintop}

\makenomenclature
\renewcommand{\nomname}{Abbreviations}
\newcommand*{\nom}[2]{#1\nomenclature{#1}{#2}}

\newcommand{\superscript}[1]{\ensuremath{^{\textrm{#1}}}}
\newcommand{\subscript}[1]{\ensuremath{_{\textrm{#1}}}}

\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{code}{Verbatim}{fontsize=\small}
\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{example}{Verbatim}{fontsize=\small}
\begin{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for posting a working example! At the same time, much of your code does not seem to be relevant to the question you're asking here. Please limit the example to only the code required for your issue to appear. You can have a look at [this guide for how to prune your code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/3225) for this purpose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The full error message is

```
Package biblatex Warning: Conflicting options.
(biblatex)                'firstinits' conflicts with 'uniquename=full'.
(biblatex)                Setting 'uniquename=init' on input line 62.
```

see the output or `.log` file.  So it is coming from `biblatex` and is not a fatal error.  The style is setting the `uniquename` option, so I suggest you add `uniquename=init` to the options you pass to `biblatex`

Comment: Perfect, that did the trick. Thank-you very much.